# Creating the biggest array of chars which can be allocated

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I have tried to check programmatically how big an array I can allocate but my code does not seem to check it. How to make it faster? In the end I would like to get an exception.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
int ASCENDING = 1, DESCENDING = 2;

int tworzTablice(int rozmiar, char* t){
    try{
        t = new char[rozmiar];
        delete []t;
    }catch (std::bad_alloc& e){
        tworzTablice(rozmiar - 1,t);
        return -1;
    }
    return rozmiar;
}

int f(long p, long skok){
    char* t;
    try{
        while(true){
            t = new char[p];
            delete []t;
            p = p + skok;
        }
    }
  catch (std::bad_alloc& ba){
    p = tworzTablice(p-1, t);
    cout<<"blad";
  }
  return p;
}

int main(){
    cout<<f(0, 100000000)<<endl;;


    cout<<"koniec"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to know it?

Comment: It depends on the size of your RAM, I believe. And you should use delete [] t; instead of delete t; here.

Comment: Double the buffer size until allocation fails (`t == NULL`) and then binary search for the maximum allowed size.

Comment: @harpun: You better touch (commit) the memory, because if you don't most systems will allow you to allocate as much as you want...

Comment: Will be limited by two things:  Available heap, and any architectural limitation.  Eg for the latter would be an ancient implementation with 16-bit ints and hence limited to 32 or 64K elements.

Comment: I remember there being a POSIX (or maybe just linux) constant to query that would tell you the maximal memory you could allocate on the architecture you're running on (assuming the machine has sufficient RAM+Swap space). But I'm wrecking my brain as to what it was called (so, this is a comment, not an answer). Maybe I'll remember the name later.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to want to do this (unless you want to chew up someone's memory maliciously, I guess), assuming everything goes as planned, once the system starts running out of memory everything will just get really slow and unresponsive until finally the program crashes or the OS does something about the nasty process. Then, memory will be released, everything will be back to normal, and you'll probably have no idea what the size of the array that finally broke new was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Allocating all available memory is probably a *bad* idea, but if you really want to:

```
vector<char*> ptrs;
int avail;
try {
    while (true)
        ptrs.push_back(new char[1000]);
}
catch (bad_alloc& b)
{
    avail = ptrs.size() * 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < ptrs.size(); i++)
       delete[] ptrs[i];
}
```

Comment: -1 : All OP needs is a `std::string`. Really bad advice with `std::vector<char *>`

Comment: @AlokSave I assume you mean creating a `string` and growing it until it throws an exception? AFAIK, strings have to be allocated contiguously in memory, so that method will show less memory available than there really is

Comment: Yep, a contiguous data structure will only show you how much memory can be allocated contiguously, not how much memory is available in total. This answer still doesn't take into account that some OSes don't commit the memory until you try to use it, though, so it may yield false results.

Comment: @AlokSave Lol, did you read OP's question? "have tried to check by code how big array I can alocate" `std::string` is **not** an array. 
@nullptr Another thing here, is by creating "many" arrays, technically one would be cheating since each pointer could be spread out in memory, whereas a single allocation will be contiguous--a true array (with the largest size) (which, I think, is the question)

Comment: @voidptr: The Q and the answer both are imaginary and pointless. both deserved a -1. Feel free to lol, but neither the Q nor the answer have any practical use or application.

Comment: @AlokSave You might be right, but what help is a comment like that? Tell me and tell him what's wrong

Comment: @AlokSave Oh yes, I agree with Q/A being imaginary/pointless, but in that case, so is your comment since using `std::string` doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @voidptr: It solves the purpose and the functionality the program has to provide the conditions OP talks about are useless, practically never required and drawn from fancy imaginations. One needs to tell OP  how counterproductive it is not try to cater to them.

Comment: @AlokSave So was the `std::string` comment supposed to be sarcasm or irony? I don't see how either cases "tell OP how counterproductive it is." I am pretty sure the answer from nullptr says "Allocating all available memory is probably a bad idea" which informs OP of this much better than your comment did.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted, there is a way to query the OS in order to determine the maximal size of heap-allocated memory, but I can't for the heck of it remember its name.

However, you can easily find out yourself. However, you should use `malloc`/`free` instead of `new`/`delete` in order to avoid the unnecessary initialisation of all cells;

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

size_t maxMem() {
  static size_t size = 0;
  if (!size) {
    size_t m = 0;
    for (void* p = 0; (p = malloc(1<<m)); m++)
      free(p);
    while (m) {
      size_t const testSize = size + (1<<(--m));
      if (void* const p = malloc(testSize)) {
        size = testSize;
        free(p);
      }   
    }   
  }
  return size;
}

int main() {
  // forgive me for using printf, but I couldn't remember how to hex-format in std::cout
  printf("%u (hex %X)\n",int(maxMem()),int(maxMem()));
}
```

On my 64 bit machine I get

```
2147483647 (hex 7FFFFFFF)
```

while on another 32 system I get

```
2140700660 (hex 7F987FF4)
```

You can then go ahead and `new` an array of that size if you really have to. Note however, that this is the largest *consecutive* chunk you can request. The total memory your process might allocate is larger and depends on the installed RAM and the reserved swap space.